# Tricky: How to compare Dictionary values (containing lists) with a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am having a dict(containing lists) and a list, which I want to compare:

The first thing, I want to find out is whether each value-list (e.g. for issue1, the value-list is `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`) in ref has the same length as the list `abf`.

Then comes the tricky part: If they have the same length, I want to compare each item in the list `abf` with each item of the value-lists in `ref`.

But... Under one condition, the program shall move on to the next value-list in `ref` (without checking the remaining items of the current value-list), and this is if the item of the value-list is 1 and the corresponding item in the list `abf` is 0.

To make it clear, here is one example:

the value-list of the key 'issue1' in the dict ref is `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1].` The list `abf` is `[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.

Now, I want to check each item of those two lists (the first item of the value-list of issue1 with the first item of the list `abf`, then the second item of `issue1` with the second item of `abf` and so on...): As the first two items are 1 and 1 and the condition (see above) is not fulfilled, it shall go on to the next two items (which are again 1 and 1) and so on, UNTIL it gets to (in this case) the seventh items (which are 1 and 0). At this point it shall stop comparing value-list of `issue1` with list `abf` and continue with comparing the next value-list (of `issue2`) with the list `abf`. I hope you get the idea!

Here is my code so far:

```
## ref is a dict with lists as values, abf is a list
ref = {'issue1': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
       'issue2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       'issue3': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
abf = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

## getting the length of the lists in ref and abf ans save them in ref_total & abf_total
for key in ref:
    [int(item) for item in ref[key]]
ref_total = len(ref[key])
abf_total = len(abf)

## check whether ref_total and abf_total has same value
if ref_total == abf_total:
    for key, value in ref.items():
        for j in value:
            if (ref[key][j] == 1) and (abf[j] == 0): ## if item in ref is 1 and in abf is 0, go on to the next value-list
                break
            if j == abf_total-1: ## if he compared the whole value-list of the current key of ref with abf and the condition above did not occur, save the key of this value-list in resp!
                resp = ref[key]

else:
    resp = 'Length of strings varies!' ##if the lists don't have the same length

print resp ##let me know, which key "went through"
```

I am really looking forward to your responeses. The code does not work and I have no idea why!

Comment: Please be more specific than "the code does not work". What exactly happens when you run it, and what are you expecting?

Comment: You should put equality as a function, and then call it (you can also test this function, and therefore this part of your code).

Comment: The list comprehension in the `for key in ref:` block does nothing that I can see...

Comment: I can't understand your problem, but maybe you want to use tuples as elements instead of lists?

Comment: Your description sounds to me like the normal way the Python compares lists.

Comment: your indentation looks way off in that code . . . you have a `for key in ref`, and you refer to key in many spots later in code that's not part of that for block . . .

Comment: There is a problem with your indentation.Every line from `ref_total..` should be indentated one block

Answer (score 0):

There are **few problems** with your code, that I would like to point: -

```
for key in ref:
    [int(item) for item in ref[key]]
```

To start with, your above loop is ambiguous. Its not doing anything, but just creating a list which is then ignored

Secondly,

```
ref_total = len(ref[key])
abf_total = len(abf)
```

The above assignment does not work, because you have placed it outside the for loop. Indentation problem.

```
if ref_total == abf_total:
    for key, value in ref.items():
```

In the above code segment, rather than having your `if` condition first, and then the `for` loop, you should move your `if condition` in the for loop. So, for each `key, value` pair, check whether the `len(value) == len(abf)`. If true, then continue with the inner for loop.

```
if (ref[key][j] == 1) and (abf[j] == 0)
```

This condition does not account for `abf[j] = 1` and `ref[key][j] = 0`. Instead of checking the inequality, you can check the equality, and just take a negation of that. That would be easier. (**EDIT: -** *Just noticed that, you just want to check it for that condition only. So you can ignore this change).*

Also, your inner loop should not be `for j in value`. You cannot index on `j` then. Use `for j in range(ref_list)`, to compare values at each index.

---

You can try out this code after the above changes: -

```
ref = {'issue1': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
       'issue2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       'issue3': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       'issue4': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]}
abf = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
abf_total = len(abf)  # Since it will never change. Move it outside

for key, value in ref.items():
    resp = ""
    ref_total = len(value)        

    if ref_total == abf_total:
        for j in range(ref_total):

            if not (value[j] == abf[j]): 
                break
            if j == abf_total-1: 
                resp = value
                print resp

    else:
        resp = 'Length of strings varies!' ##if the lists don't have the same length
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some notes as comment, but this should work:

```
## ref is a dict with lists as values, abf is a list
ref = {'issue1': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       'issue2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'issue3': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
abf = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

# abf_total does not change during cycle. Calculate it outside.
abf_total = len(abf)

## getting the length of the lists in ref and abf ans save them in ref_total & abf_total
for key, items in ref.iteritems():
    ref_total = len(items)

    ## check whether ref_total and abf_total has same value
    if ref_total == abf_total:
        # Here 'ref' screened the outside ref. Use 'i'
        for i, value in enumerate(items):
            if (items[i] == 1) and (abf[i] == 0): ## if item in ref is 1 and in abf is 0, go on to the next value-list
                break
        if i == abf_total-1:
            # if he compared the whole value-list of the current key of ref with abf and the condition above did not occur, save the key of
this value-list in resp!
            resp = "%s = %s" % (key, items)
    else:
        resp = 'Length of strings varies!' ##if the lists don't have the same length

print resp ##let me know, which key "went through"
```

The output is:

```
issue2 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement right, Python has that functionality built in. You can do this.

```
ref = {'issue1': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
       'issue2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       'issue3': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}

abf = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

abf == abf
# OUT: True


def findinref(d, abf):
    for key, value in ref.items():
        if value == abf:
            return value
    return None

findinref(ref, abf)

findinref(ref, [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1])
# OUT: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all very very much, you are really awesome! I didn't expect that much feedback!! You really helped me a lot. I went for Rohit Jain's solution - thank you very much Rohit!! Here is the complete code (if there is space for improvements, don't hesitate to critizise me! any feedback is really appreciated!!)

```
ref = {'issue1': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
       'issue2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       'issue3': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
abf = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

abf_total = len(abf)

for key, value in ref.items():
    ref_total = len(ref[key])   
    if ref_total == abf_total:
        i = -1
        for j in value:
            i += 1
            if (j == 1) and (abf[i] == 0):
                break
            if i == len(abf)-1:
                resp = key
    else:
        resp = 'Length of strings varies!'
print resp
```